# Comparing a cell with a vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell `A` in Matlab of dimension `1x3`, e.g.

```
A={{1,2,3,4} {5,6} {7,8,9} }
```

`A` contains all the integers from `1` to `n` in increasing order. In the example `n=9`. However, the number of elements within each sub-cell can be different. Each sub-cell is non-empty.

Consider the vector `B` of dimension `nx1` containing some integers from `1` to `n` in increasing order (repetitions are allowed), e.g.

```
B=[1 1 2 2 4 7 7 8 9]'
```

I want to construct (without using loops) the vector `C` of dimension `nx1` such that each `C(i)` tells which sub-cell of `A` `B(i)` belongs to. In the example

```
C=[1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3]'
```

Comment: why no for loops? They can be pretty fast nowadays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that structure, `A` is uniquely determined by the number of elements of each of its cells, and the result can be obtained as

```
C = sum(bsxfun(@gt, B, cumsum(cellfun(@numel, A))), 2)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's faster than `for` loops, but how about

```
C = arrayfun(@(b) find(cellfun(@(a) any(cell2mat(a) == b), A)), B);
```

Explanation: pick each element `b` in `B`; then pick every sub-cell `a` in `A` and check for equality with `b`, return the index of sub-cell `b` is a member of.